# Foreign Key and Index creation in referential order using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ddl

I am trying to write a java application which copies tables to another schema.

If I simply use the result from `show create table foo_bar` in the target schema, I get errors if referenced tables for foreign keys are not created yet. So I build my own scripts using `DatabaseMetaData` [[getTables()]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) to create the tables, without the foreign keys. After creating all the tables, I will add the FKs. And this is where trouble begins.

Since I can not (and do not want to) manually sort these FK scripts, I'm looking for a way to run these in order, depending on the references they have.

Is there a way to generate these scripts in referential order, maybe a third party java library buried deep in the internet? Or is there no escape from running all these alter table scripts one by one, until program receives no errors? What is the best approach to this problem?

I am using `jdbc` to connect `mysql` using `innodb storage engine`. If answer contains comparison information about other rdbms as well, much appreciated.

Comment: There is `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0` and `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`. If you know the source database is consistent, do this when inserting into the target. You can also use mysqldump which can (or will by default) add these statements into its output.

Comment: @marekful Thanks for the comment but I'm not having problems when inserting data. Problem is, my application can not alter the tables in correct order every time, to add foreign keys. Looking for a solution to create the foreign keys in correct order.

Comment: Do a mysqldump of the tables into 'file.sql' from source. On target, do `myqsl ..... < file.sql`. All will be fine. Also, if you want to create just the table structures (with all indexes/keys), do the same but pass `--nod-data` to mysqldump.

Comment: `mysqldump automatically includes a statement in the dump output to set foreign_key_checks to 0. This avoids problems with tables having to be reloaded in a particular order` and `This enables you to import the tables in any order if the dump file contains tables that are not correctly ordered for foreign keys.` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @marekful Well, I wasn't planning to use dump files. I prefer building and running queries within the java application (don't ask why, I might add extra columns at some point) but since you mentioned I will give it a try to see the results.

Comment: You don't have to use mysqldump. Getting show create table statements and executing them on the target will work regardless of order of tables with foreign_key_checks=0. You can issue this statement "manually", too. It will avoid errors not just on data insert but on adding foreign keys whose referenced table doesn't exist yet.